# Developing a spark streaming application

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

so the problem i'm trying to tackle is the following:

- I need a data source that emits messages at a certain frequency
- There are N neural nets that need to process each message individually
- The outputs from all neural nets are aggregated and only when all N outputs for each message are collected, should a message be declared fully processed
- At the end i should measure the time it took for a message to be fully processed (time between when it was emitted and when all N neural net outputs from that message have been collected)

I'm curious as to how one would approach such a task using spark streaming.

My current implementation uses 3 types of components: a custom receiver and two classes that implement Function, one for the neural nets, one for the end aggregator.

In broad strokes, my application is built as follows:

```
JavaReceiverInputDStream<...> rndLists = jssc.receiverStream(new JavaRandomReceiver(...));

Function<JavaRDD<...>, Void> aggregator = new JavaSyncBarrier(numberOfNets);

for(int i = 0; i < numberOfNets; i++){
    rndLists.map(new NeuralNetMapper(neuralNetConfig)).foreachRDD(aggregator);
}
```

The main problem i'm having with this, though, is that it runs faster in local mode than when submitted to a 4-node cluster.

Is my implementation wrong to begin with or is something else happening here ?

There's also a full post here http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/Developing-a-spark-streaming-application-td12893.html with more details regarding the implementation of each of the three components mentioned previously.

Answer (score 5):

It seems there might be a lot of repetitive instantiation and serialization of objects. The later might be hitting your performance in a cluster.

You should try instantiating your neural networks only once. You will have to ensure that they are serializable. You should use `flatMap` instead of multiple `map`s + `union`. Something along these lines:

```java
// Initialize neural net first
List<NeuralNetMapper> neuralNetMappers = new ArrayList<>(numberOfNets);
for(int i = 0; i < numberOfNets; i++){
    neuralNetMappers.add(new NeuralNetMapper(neuralNetConfig));
}

// Then create a DStream applying all of them
JavaDStream<Result> neuralNetResults = rndLists.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<Item, Result>() {
    @Override
    public Iterable<Result> call(Item item) {
        List<Result> results = new ArrayList<>(numberOfNets);
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfNets; i++) {
            results.add(neuralNetMappers.get(i).doYourNeuralNetStuff(item));
        }
        return results;
    }
});

// The aggregation stuff
neuralNetResults.foreachRDD(aggregator);
```

If you can afford to initialize the networks this way, you can save quite a lot of time. Also, the `union` stuff you included in your linked posts seems unnecessary and is penalizing your performance: a `flatMap` will do.

Finally, in order to further tune your performance in the cluster, [you can use the Kryo serializer](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i did get around to playing with that solution on a single node and it does indeed speed things up. I have tried running this on a multi-node cluster however and there doesn't seem to be any performance increase. So my question is how would i write this in a way that benefits from a multi-node cluster ? Some general knowledge on how spark distributes workload would also help, as i didn't find many details on that aspect.

Comment: First of all, you should identify which stages are taking longer. You can use the monitorization webapp at http://localhost:4040/stages/ to sort stages by how much they're taking. Compare this output from the run in a single-node and in your cluster. Also, you'll benefit from using Spark 1.1.0, since it has much better debugging functionalities for streaming.

In that web interface, you should also look at the "Streaming" tab, where you will see how many events per second are being processed. You should probably use that in order to measure performance.

Comment: How's your cluster connected? Bad connectivity between your nodes will have a severe negative impact on performance.

Comment: Thanks again for the quick reply, connectivity shouldn't be an issue, these are 4 separate machines hooked up on the same LAN with <1 ms lag between them. I'll have a look at the stats you mentioned. In the mean time i feel i should mention that events are currently incoming at 1 per second, with the batch interval also set at 1 second (so basically exactly 1 event per second). The part that would theoretically take the most time would be the neural net processing itself (ideally i would reach a high enough number of neural nets in the hundreds) which is what i'm hoping to get parallelized.

Comment: I've also had a bit of experience with storm prior to spark, which had a bit more intuitive paradigm of distributing its work, and this is what i'm having trouble with mostly on spark, that i can't get a feel for how it parallelizes its applications.

Comment: AFAIK if you have 1 incoming event per second and a batch interval of 1 second, you are not parallelizing at all. So might be experiencing a non-parallel performance with the addition of the cluster overhead. Spark parallelizes at the RDD level. DStreams are sequences of RDD which are processed sequentially. So the parallelization happens at the RDD level, not the DStream level. Try to get more events per second or increase your batch interval.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61251/discussion-between-smola-and-andrei).